# Jackson custom serializer - changing json structure

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using jackson for serialize/deserialize purpose. Currently I need to change the default serializer.

Current json structure:

```
"navigation": [
  {
     "id": "val1", 
     "title": "val1",
     "color": "val1"
  },
  {
     "id": "val2", 
     "title": "val2",
     "color": "val2"
  }
 ]
```

I need to achieve the following structure:

```
"navigation": [
  ["id","title","color"],
  ["val1","val1","val3"],
  ["val1","val1","val3"]
]
```

I didn't find any useful description how to properly do this in jackson. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you perhaps mistype your second code block? If so you could do a translation before serialization to avoid writing a custom de/serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to implement your own Serializer/Deserializer:

http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html

The one you are using now is the one that comes out of the box, and it is not configurable in the way that you are wanting.  However, the good news is, writing your own is not too difficult.